# Can I use jump?

Tags: navigation, directories

I found this package for the bash shell that lets you quickly jump between commonly used folders: https://github.com/gsamokovarov/jump

I use it all the time now.

> Jump uses fuzzy matching to find the desired directory to jump to. This means that your search terms are patterns that match the desired directory approximately rather than exactly. Typing 2 to 5 consecutive characters of the directory name is all that jump needs to find it.

Is there a way to use this from inside of Emacs or something equivalent? One option would be to jump to a folder in the shell, then open emacs in that directory. However, it seems like a lot of people just leave emacs open all the time and navigate to files within emacs.

Edit:
Thanks! I didn't realize you could do fuzzy matching in Emacs.

By jump I mean, say I have two folders

/home/user/python/space/satellite_plotter/

/home/user/c_programs/games/pacman/

In bash with jump, if I am working in the first folder I can just type "j pac" and it will navigate to the second folder. It keeps track of often visited folders and then performs fuzzy matching on this list. I just don't know of a way to do this as quickly in Emacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by jump to a folder (directory), in Emacs?

Do you mean just change the value of `default-directory`? Do you mean open Dired on that directory? For the former, just use `M-x cd` (or bind it to a key). For the latter, just use `C-x d`.

You can use fuzzy matching for any or all inputs you type to Emacs. Even in vanilla Emacs there is now a completion style (option `completion-styles`) called `flex` that provides a simple kind of fuzzy matching.

---

UPDATE after your comment:

- For jumping among recently visited files (and directories), use library `recentf`.
- For jumping among buffers in the current session, just use `C-x b`.
- For jumping among specific places in buffers or files, use Emacs bookmarks. If you use [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then you can quickly bookmark positions [without needing to name them](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutonamedBookmarks), and the bookmarks can be [temporary](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#TemporaryBookmarks) (not persist across Emacs sessions), if you like.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize you could do fuzzy matching in Emacs.
By jump I mean, say I have two folders



-/home/user/python/space/satellite_plotter/
-/home/user/c_programs/games/pacman/



In bash with jump, if I am working in the first folder I can just type "j pac" and it will navigate to the second folder. It keeps track of often visited folders and then performs fuzzy matching on this list. I just don't know of a way to do this as quickly in Emacs.

Comment: Please put all such info in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time.